# How can I generate a pandas date range with a frequency of Tue to Sat inclusive?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, range, datetimeindex

I am trying to generate a datetime index with pandas that has a custom daily frequency.

At the moment, I can generate the following datetime index:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2020,8,28),end=dt.datetime(2020,9,30),freq='B')

DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-28', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-02',
               '2020-09-03', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-07', '2020-09-08',
               '2020-09-09', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-14',
               '2020-09-15', '2020-09-16', '2020-09-17', '2020-09-18',
               '2020-09-21', '2020-09-22', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-24',
               '2020-09-25', '2020-09-28', '2020-09-29', '2020-09-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

However, this returns all the business days.  I want to return all the Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri and Sat days instead.  Perhaps this can be done with some kind of custom set up or some kind of offset?  Specifically, is there a way to do it directly using the date_range functionality and the freq input?  If not, how can this be achieved the most simply?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just add a day with `Timedelta`, but to not change the daterange you want, you need to remove a day when creating the boundaries.

```
(pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2020,8,27),end=dt.datetime(2020,9,29),freq='B') 
  + pd.Timedelta(days=1))

DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-28', '2020-08-29', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-02',
               '2020-09-03', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-05', '2020-09-08',
               '2020-09-09', '2020-09-10', '2020-09-11', '2020-09-12',
               '2020-09-15', '2020-09-16', '2020-09-17', '2020-09-18',
               '2020-09-19', '2020-09-22', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-24',
               '2020-09-25', '2020-09-26', '2020-09-29', '2020-09-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

EDIT: you can also define your `CustomBusinessDay`

```
cbd = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')
pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2020,8,28),end=dt.datetime(2020,9,30),freq=cbd)
```

Comment: This loses the first day and adds an extra day on at the end though.  I do see that this is effectively the same as producing the original index and then shifting it by 1 with a frequency of 'B'.  I guess I was trying to avoid that and then the further code required to tidy up the front and the back of the datetimeindex.

Comment: The Edit you provided is a much sharper solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

With `dayofweek`

```
idx = pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2020,8,28),end=dt.datetime(2020,9,30))
s = idx.dayofweek
idx[s.isin([2,3,4,5])]
```

---

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-28', '2020-08-29', '2020-09-02', '2020-09-03',
           '2020-09-04', '2020-09-05', '2020-09-09', '2020-09-10',
           '2020-09-11', '2020-09-12', '2020-09-16', '2020-09-17',
           '2020-09-18', '2020-09-19', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-24',
           '2020-09-25', '2020-09-26', '2020-09-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This needs to include 1 also though right.  This idx[s.isin([2,3,4,5])] should read idx[s.isin([1,2,3,4,5])].

Comment: That is what I thought at first, but it seems to include Sunday when I run it with 2,3,4,5,6.